# Graphene and Django about relationships

Tags: python, django, graphene-python, graphene-django

I'm very new to Graphene and testing it to see if i could use it for a Django project with complex queries. To test it, i'm trying to create an Ecommerce with the following models

```
class Sku(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ProductSku(models.Model):
    sku = models.ForeignKey(Sku, related_name='product_sku', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='product_sku', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

As you can see here Product and Sku have a many to many relationship using the model ProductSku

Using the documentation from Graphene i created the following Schema

```
class SkuNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Sku


class ProductNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

class ProductSkuNode(DjangoObjectType):     
    class Meta:
        model = ProductSku



class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_products = graphene.List(ProductNode, name=graphene.String())

    product = graphene.Field(ProductNode, id=graphene.Int())

    def resolve_all_products(self, info, **args):
        name = args.get('name')
        if name is not None:
            return Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=name)
        return Product.objects.all()

    def resolve_product(self, info, **args):
        id = args.get('id')
        if id is not None:
            return Product.objects.filter(pk=id).first()
```

Right now my frontend app could get the price of a given product for a given sku by doing a query that asks for

```
query{
  allProducts{
    id,
    name,
    productSku{
      price,
      sku{
        id,
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But what i want to do is a query that asks for the price inside the SkuNode

```
query{
  allProducts{
    id,
    name,
    sku{
      id,
      name,
      price
    }
  }
}
```

Is that posible?

Comment: Feels like SKU should not be it's own model in the first place. It's just an attribute of a product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a sku field and resolver to `ProductNode` like:

```
class ProductNode(DjangoObjectType):
    sku = graphene.Field(SkuNode)

    class Meta:
        model = Product

    def resolve_sku(self, info):
        return self.product_sku.sku # (however you get the Sku object from a Product instance)
```

Then you'll have a `sku` field as part of the product response.  But since what you're asking for is to mix fields from both the `Sku` and the `ProductSku` models, you are probably better off creating a new object type that is not a model type, it's just an `ObjectType` with 3 fields (id, name, price) and then dynamically returning an instance of that.  So in that case you should do this for `ProductNode`

```
class ProductNode(DjangoObjectType):
    sku = graphene.Field(SkuObjectType)

    class Meta:
        model = Product

    def resolve_sku(self, info):
        sku = self.product_sku.sku
        return SkuObjectType(id=sku.id, name=sku.name, price=self.product_sky.price)
```

And you'd create the `SkuObjectType` like

```
class SkuNode(DjangoObjectType):
    id = graphene.ID()
    name = graphene.String()
    price = graphene.Int()
```